# How does the Ternary Operator work in this piece of code?

Tags: java

I have a small piece of code of a function to set color that looks like this:

```
private Color color = Color.CYAN;

public void setColor(Color c) {
        color = c != null ?c :color;
        repaint();
    }
```

Does it means something like this?

```
color = c;
if (c != null) {
        color = c;
        } else {
        c = color;
}
```

I can't really wrap my head around this piece of code. Please enlighten me.

Comment: The ternary is always `boolean-expression ? value-if-true : value-if-false`. Your if-else mixes all sorts of things around. (To be fair, the ternary code is unnecessarily complicated and could be replaced with a trivial `if`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more like

```
if (c != null) {
    color = c;
} else {
    color = color;
}
```

which, in turn, because `color = color;` essentially does nothing, is the same as:

```
if (c != null) {
    color = c;
}
```

Comment: Since functionally they are the same, is there any reasons the Ternary Operator should be used over the if-statement in this scenario and in general? Thank you.