# Boolean syntax. Please explain

Tags: java

Can someone please explain this java syntax for me.
`public boolean isDead() { return numFightersAlive() == 0 ? true : false; }`
I am new to java and I was wondering what kind of syntax that is. Normally I would create a variable and return the boolean variable but it's my first time seeing a question mark in a code.

Comment: It is called a ternary operator.

Comment: Note that this is an example of a _really bad use_ of the ternary, since you can just as easily say `return numFightersAlive() == 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called ternary. It's a shortened version of an if, but it's not better than an if all the time.

The syntax of a ternary is as follows:

```
(condition) ? result in case of being true: result in case of being false
```

In this case:
The return is asking a condition. Is the condition equal to zero?

If it is true, return will have a true value, if it is false return will have a false value.

```
public boolean isDead() { return numFightersAlive() == 0 ? true : false; }
```

Answer (score 2):

After the question mark is the "then" part, after colon is the "else" part.

So this is shorthand syntax for

```
if (numFightersAlive() == 0) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

It can actually be simplified to be just

```
return numFightersAlive() == 0
```

This would give an equivalent result

Comment: To add in, a while ago I asked something very similar and OP might want to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64096020/how-does-the-ternary-operator-work-in-this-piece-of-code